# Why is antiderivative only taken for the integrand?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I understand that integration is the summation of the small areas which are given by $f(x)\,dx$, but while taking the antiderivative/integrating we only consider the $f(x)$.

For example: While solving $\displaystyle \int x\,dx$ we take the antiderivative of $x$, which is $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$.

So what happened to the $dx$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It is only a symbol: we write the $dx$ in the integration operation in order to specify that we are integrating along the $x$ variables (maybe there are others). The same for the symbol $\dfrac {d}{dx}$ used in derivation.

Comment: Obviously, the historical origin of the symbolism has to do with a "quasi-algebraic" view of the two operations: derivation and integration. In a sense: $\frac {d}{dx}(\int f(x) dx)$ is like "composing" the two operations that are one the inverse of the others, and thus the result is the original $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original concept of the integral, the $dx$ is representing an infinitesimal width, and the integral sign is a summation over all those infinitesimal widths. (The integral sign is shaped like an "s" because it stands for "sum"). So the $dx$ disappears because you've added them all up. Then, because of the fundamental theorem of calculus saying that integration and antidifferentiation are very closely related, the same notation got applied to that.

As time went on, the definition of the derivative and integral changed to be more general, but the notation stayed, with $dx$ becoming a marker for what variable is being integrated over.

Answer (score 0):

The $dx$ is there to specify that we are taking the integral with respect to $x$. This means that $x$ is the variable in our equation. This is important because if the dx had changed to $dy$, we would treat $x$ like a constant and our answer would be $xy + C$. The $dx$ then disappears after you take the integral, because all it tells us is which variable we use.